# Custom Seekbar extremities issue

Tags: android

Any ideas on what that small thing at the end is? If i set the progress to 0 and remove the thumb, it's the same thing on the left side.
I've noticed that it's the place where the thumb goes to when it's at the extreme right (and left as well), but I can't seem to be able to remove it.

[image]

This is the xml I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:dither="true"
            android:src="@drawable/filler_bar_bckgnd_white"
            />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <bitmap
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:src="@drawable/filler_bar_bckgnd_green"
                />
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <bitmap
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:src="@drawable/filler_bar_bckgnd_green"
                />
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And I'm setting it like so:

```
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/my_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="40"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/filler_bar_icon" />
```

These are the images used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: Try to change android:dither="true" t to `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the issue. The problem was that 9patch image. I've played around with it and it seems that I should have done it this way:

[image]